Dell R640 compability with 3rd party raid controller
I have a DELL R640 server.
It does not natively support harware NVME RAID.
If I purchase a card such as a Megaraid 9460-16i, will I be able to fit that into the server and connect the cables from the backplane to the server?
This is the kind of card I am looking for: https://www.ebay.com/itm/134793155266
This is kind of a generic thing, so I would expect to be able to get this to work, but I have received some negative responses with vague justifications, so I wonder if there is indeed an issue.
Am I missing something here in terms of compatibility? Drive leds blinking or not being on in the caddies would not be a problem, as long as it works.

please do not just downvote or vote for closing. Be helpful, be insightful. If the question doesn't fit your standards, comment so it can be improved. Downvoting or voting for closing without any added information is useless.
